# I Have tried to test multiple URLs in Jmeter for Load Testing with CSV file but it seems to be not getting result

Tags: jmeter

I have taken 200 users at a time and ramp up period is 100 seconds.I entered URLs in the CSV file, added path and variables for respective folder in the Jmeter. It also display the results for users but the ramp up period is continuously going on and on. Even though I take 100 seconds it goes up to 2 hours. So is there any alternating way to test the multiple URLs at a time or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ramp-up period doesn't have anything in common with test duration, if you have 200 users and 100 seconds ramp-up it basically mean that JMeter will add 2 users each second for 100 seconds instead of starting all 200 users at the same moment. More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)

   Once kicked off each user will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down for the number of iterations defined in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or for the duration specified in the Thread Group.
2. Default [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup means that:

   - each user reads next line from the CSV file on each iteration (controllable by "Sharing Mode")
   - when the end of file is reached it starts over from the beginning (controllable by "Recycle on EOF" and "Stop thread on EOF")

So depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. If you want your test to stop after 100 seconds you need to amend your Thread Group configuration like:

   [image]
2. If you want your test to visit all URLs from the CSV file and then stop - amend your CSV Data Set Configuration to look like:

   [image]